# Spring Boot blows up when using solrj but not spring-boot-starter-data-solr

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to port an existing Spring application across to Spring Boot. I am **NOT** using the spring-boot-starter-data-solr starter however I have apache solrj (5.0.0) on my classpath.

During startup the app blows up. It seems that spring boot sees the solr classes and assumes that I also have spring-boot-starter-data-solr on the classpath. In particular I get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @ConditionalOnMissingBean
>   annotations must specify at least one bean (type, name or annotation)

If I drop the solrj dependency and use spring-boot-starter-data-solr instead it is ok. However I don't need the spring-data-solr integration and doing so will force me to backport our app to the 4.7.x release of solr.

Is anyone aware of a workaround for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So it seems the problem was caused by spring boot's dependency on solrj 4.7.x whereas I am using 5.0.0

I fixed it by using

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SolrAutoConfiguration.class})
```

To tell boot to ignore the SolrAutoConfiguration completely.

Comment: The underlying cause is that 5.0 isn't a drop-in replacement for 4.7 as it includes some breaking API changes. I imagine that Spring Boot will support Solr 5.0 as and when Spring Data Solr moves to 5.0. In the meantime I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2795) to improve the diagnostics.